# Pivotal quantities question in Bayesian Analysis, why the prior distribution is $p(\theta)\propto 1/\theta$?

Tags: statistics, bayesian

I'm reading the classical Gelman's [Bayesian Data Analysis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1439840954) and on page 54 he states

[image]

> My questions are:
>
> 1. Why $p(\theta)\propto 1/\theta$? It shouldn't be $p(\theta)=\frac{y}{\theta}$?
> 2. For me $p(\log(\theta))=\frac{1}{\log(\theta)}$, I didn't understand why he wrote $p(\log\theta)\propto 1$

Comment: (1) the statistic $y$ is just a constant so will cancel in the posterior, and you won't know $y$ when forming the prior. (2) $p(\log\theta)$ doesn't mean with $\log\theta$ plug in the function, but the prior for $\log\theta$, recall the transformation rule for densities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gelman's notation, using the same letter $p$ for various different functions, is obnoxious.

The expression $\propto\dfrac1\theta$ is implied by $=\dfrac1\theta.$ To say that something${}\propto\dfrac 1\theta$ means that something${}=\dfrac{\text{constant}}\theta,$ and "constant" means not depending on $\theta.$ So if${}=\dfrac y\theta$ is correct, then${}\propto\dfrac1\theta$ is correct.

Next recall that $\left(1\cdot d\log\theta=\dfrac{d\theta}\theta\right)$  so that is where the "$1$" comes from.